# Cant' see a AddLuceneWork message in ActiveMQ

Tags: java, hibernate, activemq-classic, hibernate-search

I've Hibernate in cluster mode, which uses ActiveMQ to send messages between nodes. The first time when I tried to see a AddLuceneWork message body an error was shown, but I added the JAR with the missing class in the ACTIVE_MQ/lib. After that another error was shown:

```
Cannot display ObjectMessage body. Reason: Failed to build body from content.
Serializable class not available to broker. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
Forbidden class org.hibernate.search.backend.AddLuceneWork!
This class is not trusted to be serialized as ObjectMessage payload.
Please take a look at http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html for more information on how to configure trusted classes.
```

So, according to the documentation I added this line to the ACTIVE_MQ/bin/env file:

```
ACTIVEMQ_OPTS="$ACTIVEMQ_OPTS -Dorg.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES=*"
```

And this lead me to an exception in the console:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /message.jsp at line 186

183:    </thead>
184:    <tbody>
185:      <tr>
186:        <td><div class="message"><pre class="prettyprint"><c:out value="${requestContext.messageQuery.body}"/></pre></div></td>
187:      </tr>
188:    </tbody>
189:  </table>
```

This is the whole stacktrace:

```
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)[apache-jsp-8.0.9.M3.jar:2.3]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)[apache-jsp-8.0.9.M3.jar:2.3]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:405)[apache-jsp-8.0.9.M3.jar:2.3]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:349)[apache-jsp-8.0.9.M3.jar:2.3]
at org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet.service(JettyJspServlet.java:107)[apache-jsp-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)[tomcat-servlet-api-8.0.24.jar:]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)[spring-web-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)[spring-web-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
at org.apache.activemq.web.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:45)[activemq-web-5.13.4.jar:5.13.4]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
at org.apache.activemq.web.filter.ApplicationContextFilter.doFilter(ApplicationContextFilter.java:102)[file:/home/openkm/activemq-5.13.4/webapps/admin/WEB-INF/classes/:]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:542)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:542)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_121]
```

It's possible to show the information I want?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry but we can't help you if you don't show the error. the JSP page is probably not relevant?

Comment: Sorry, I've completed the info.

Comment: did you resolve this problem? can u share the solution?

Comment: I haven't solved the problem, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

It happens when your java class have dependencies which are still missing from classpath of activemq or not implement Serializable interface. To resolve this try adding all dependencies to activemq classpath.

**Edit:**
Replicated same Error in my machine and above solution worked for me.
Created two Java classes

```
import java.io.Serializable;
public class MyBean1 implements Serializable{
    public String f1;
    public String f2;
}
```

and

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
public class MyBean2 implements Serializable {
    public String f1;
    public Logger f2;
}
```

and built a jar (without Logger class in it). then configured jar in activemq as mentioned [here](https://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage).
Finally create java objects of both class and send it to queue.

```
public class ActiveMqConnection {
    private static String url = "tcp://localhost:61616";
    private static String subject = "TEST_QUEUE";
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();
        Session session = connection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Destination destination = session.createQueue(subject);

        // MessageProducer is used for sending beans to the queue.
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
 MyBean1 bean1 = new MyBean1();
        bean1.f1 = "Tom";
        bean1.f2 = "John";

        Message message1 = session.createObjectMessage(bean1);
        producer.send(message1);//This bean message1 you will be able to see it in ActiveMq


        MyBean2 bean2 = new MyBean2();
        bean2.f1 = "Jerry";
//        bean2.f2 = 1;
        bean2.f2 = LogManager.getLogger();
        Message message2 = session.createObjectMessage(bean2);
        producer.send(message2);//This will throw Error when you try to view it in ActiveMq

        System.out.println("done");
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

Observe here Logger class is not present in jar file which was configured in activemq. to resolve it try adding log4j-api to activemq classpath it will resolve the error

Comment: can you please provide some sample implementation urls